# QC to QAComplete migration experience

Tags: quality-center

Wanted to get inputs on experience in migrating QC to QAComplete. Please can you share your inputs and share your email contact if you are ok to receive specific questions
thanks,
Vimal

Comment: Welcome to SQA, Vimal. This is currently not a good fit for the format here. Consider editing it so those specific questions are in the post itself so people may answer them, and others may then improve on those answers.